# How to call RTK query Everytime a Page Loads

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, rtk-query

I have to getAllCartItems Endpoint EveryTime The cart Page Loads , I tried to call it With useEffect but That gives Error because We cant call a hook inside a hook . Is there any other way i can call this getAllCartItems hook Everytime i open cart Page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "every time the page loads", but if you mean "every time the component mounts", you can just set [refetchOnMountOrArgChange​](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/cache-behavior#encouraging-re-fetching-with-refetchonmountorargchange)

```
// Forcing refetch on component mount

import { useGetPostsQuery } from './api'

const Component = () => {
  const { data } = useGetPostsQuery(
    { count: 5 },
    // this overrules the api definition setting,
    // forcing the query to always fetch when this component is mounted
    { refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true }
  )

  return <div>...</div>
}
```

Comment: what i mean is everytime i open the cart page

Comment: So probably every time the component mounts. Then use that option on your hook.

Comment: i didn't get you , can you elaborate??

Comment: I have copy-pasted the code example from the documentation page I already linked into my answer.

Comment: Thanks It's working , but what do count 5 do??

Comment: sir i just checked your profile , your creator of rtk query , my mind's blown , truly unsung hero

Comment: that's just an example of an argument you pass into the query - could also be `undefined` if you don't need an argument.